Do you know how to install the 'ODBC Driver 17 for PostgreSQL' on a Databricks cluster?
I am attempting to run postgreSQL stored procedures , through Azure Databricks notebooks .
We have stored procedure written in Azure Database for PostgreSQL and want to run postgreSQL stored procedures through Azure Databricks Notebook (using Pyspark/SQL).
Step 1: Install required libraries
Step 2: Connect with Azure Database for PostgreSQL using ODBC
 import pyodbc 
 conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER=*{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}*;'                   'SERVER=mydatabe.database.azure.net;' 'DATABASE=AdventureWorks;UID=jonnyFast;' 'PWD=MyPassword')

Step 3: Execute stored procedure in Databricks
{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server} - Do you know how to install the 'ODBC Driver 17 for PostgreSQL' on a Databricks cluster?

What error massage do you get?

According to this, there are two methods to connect to a PostgreSQL database:

Using JDBC
Using the PostgreSQL connector in Databricks Runtime.

You can use the code below to call a stored procedure from a PostgreSQL database:
import psycopg2
# Replace with your database configuration
config = {
    "dbname": "<dbname>",
    "user": "<userName>",
    "password": "<password>",
    "host": "<host>"
}
conn = psycopg2.connect(**config)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CALL insert_students('FF', 33);")

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM students')
data = cur.fetchall()
for i in data:
    print(i)

The data will be inserted into the table successfully by calling stored procedure, as shown below:

For more information, you can refer to this.
